# How to Change Vercel Deployments to Not Use Previous Build Cache by Default?

Tags: vercel

Some of my Vercel deployments for a project don't work as expected because of previous build cache.

Is there a way to disable using previous build cache by default for deployments for a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip the Build cache, Use an Environment Variable `VERCEL_FORCE_NO_BUILD_CACHE` with a value of `1` on your project